# Un campo que debe obtener la suma de un campo por si mismo no quiere sumarse (Microsoft Access)

Tags: vba, ms-access

Tengo un problema haciendo un campo de =Suma en Access, el campo no quiere sumarse no importa lo que haga. Simplemente en vez de mostrar la suma, muestra "#Error"

Este es el modulo que tengo. El campo de mas abajo debe obtener la suma de todos los  campos de Total Bs. Lo que he intentado es: Ponerlos en el detalle, tratar de hacerlo en VBA, usar de DSum

Como ven en esta imagen, esto no está sumando y no quiere sumar y mandar los datos a donde dice Sub_Total
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la estructura en factura
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es todo el codigo que tengo

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Comando30_Click()
MsgBox "INSTRUCCIONES:" & vbCrLf & "1) Dele click a Nueva Factura para que se genere el registro vació, luego vaya y dele click a id_producto para colocar una id de producto para poderse traer sus datos" & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf & "2) Dele click a los campos de texto de Subtotal, IVA, Remanente y Total para que se guarden en unas variables ocultas y luego dele click al botón de Guardar Factura para que se guarde bien todo" & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf & "3) Si quiere imprimir la factura, dele click al botón del menú donde dice 'Facturas hechas' y dele click al botón de imprimir y luego presione el botón de imprimir en este formulario y seleccione 'Registro seleccionado', si intenta imprimirlo desde aquí sin hacer ese paso no podrá hacerlo debido a las limitaciones de Microsoft Access", vbInformation
End Sub


Private Sub Texto14_GotFocus()
Me.Sub_total = Me.[txtSub_total] 'Igualar al subtotal'
End Sub

Private Sub txtIVA_GotFocus()
Me.IVA = Me.[txtIVA]
End Sub

Private Sub txtTotal_GotFocus()
Me.Total = Me.[txtTotal]
End Sub
```

Esta es la estructura en Detalle_Factura
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es todo el codigo que tengo

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Op1_AfterUpdate()
Dim vResult As Long 'Resultado'
vResult = Nz(Me.txtResultado.Value, 0)
Me.Sub_total.Value = vResult 'Convierte el subtotal en el resultado'
End Sub

Private Sub Op2_AfterUpdate()
Call Op1_AfterUpdate 'Llama a Op1'
End Sub
```

Dejare un enlace con la base de datos, los modulos de DETALLE_FACTURA y FACTURA son los que tienen problemas
https://filebin.net/x6reffi9qpfih27u/Inventario_simple.accdb?t=gi7bp719

La respuesta debe mandarme el archivo arreglado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes la base de datos muy liada y parece que no manejas los conceptos básicos.
Para poder sumar el total de tus facturas, primero tienes que cambiar la estructura de tus tablas/consultas, dependiendo de como lo quieras hacer, calculando el campo total (unidad*precio). Si optas por calcularlo a nivel de tabla, lo puedes hacer cambiado el tipo de campo a "calculado" (introduciendo la fórmula para dicho campo, que afectará a todos los registros de la tabla. Si optas por hacerlo a nivel de consulta, en el diseño de la consulta puedes crear un campo que sume unidad*precio. Una vez hecho eso, y teniendo claro el diseño,  desde un formulario ya podrás usar la función suma del total ya calculado previamente...